# Dynamically compare two arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to compare two arrays, one being called `values` and other one called `feeds`.
The `feeds` array has multiple set of values, how can I check which feed contains the correct set of values to match?
Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/v7ussmbb/1/

I understand the async nature, ie console.log rules before the loop completes which is fine, I just need the comparison part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would iterate all your feeds until one matches all the rules, to achieve that I would do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/canastro/v7ussmbb/4/

```
// Hold the active feed
var active_feed = '';

// Iterate until one item matches all rules
const found = feeds.some(function(item) {
  //console.log('item: ', item);

  // Check if all rules match
    const match = item.rules.some(function(rule) {

    // Get rule to apply by comparing values keys with the rule id
    let ruleToApply;
    Object.keys(values).some(function(key) {
      const isRule = key === String(rule.id);
      if (isRule) { ruleToApply = values[key]; }
      return isRule;
    });

    return ruleToApply === rule.value;
  });

  if (match) { active_feed = item; }

  return match;
});

console.log('active_feed: ', active_feed);
```

To achieve this I used `some` function:

> some() executes the callback function once for each element present in
>   the array until it finds one where callback returns a truthy value (a
>   value that becomes true when converted to a Boolean). If such an
>   element is found, some() immediately returns true. Otherwise, some()
>   returns false. callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which
>   have assigned values; it is not invoked for indexes which have been
>   deleted or which have never been assigned values.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: While it works, it only compares the first object in rules array, https://jsfiddle.net/v7ussmbb/5/